# PHP MySQL query to CSV -- multiple fields for one attribute

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm trying to create a CSV file that has a MySQL query's output.
The problem that I'm having is that for one of the columns, I have multiple fields associated to the "entity_id" so it duplicates the row with just the "value" field different. Rather, I want to have the "value" field be in a new column within the CSV in the same row as the other related information.

Here is the relevant parts of the code:

```
$sqlQuery = mysql_query('SELECT  `sales_flat_order`.`increment_id` ,  `sales_flat_order`.`created_at` ,  `sales_flat_order`.`status` ,  `sales_flat_order`.`shipping_amount` ,  `sales_flat_order`.`grand_total` ,  `sales_flat_order`.`shipping_description` , `sales_flat_order`.`customer_email` ,  `sales_flat_order`.`customer_note` , `sales_flat_order_item`.`item_id` ,  `sales_flat_order_item`.`sku` ,  `sales_flat_order_item`.`qty_ordered` ,  `sales_flat_order_item`.`row_total` , `sales_flat_order`.`customer_firstname` ,  `sales_flat_order`.`customer_lastname`, `street`, `city`, `region`,`postcode`, `country_id`, `telephone`, `company`, `aitoc_order_entity_custom`.`value`
        FROM sales_flat_order
        INNER JOIN  `sales_flat_order_item` ON  `sales_flat_order`.`entity_id` =  `sales_flat_order_item`.`order_id` 
        INNER JOIN  `sales_flat_quote_item` ON  `sales_flat_order_item`.`quote_item_id` =  `sales_flat_quote_item`.`item_id` 
        INNER JOIN  `sales_flat_quote_address` ON  `sales_flat_quote_item`.`quote_id` =  `sales_flat_quote_address`.`quote_id` 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `aitoc_order_entity_custom` ON `sales_flat_order`.`entity_id` = `aitoc_order_entity_custom`.entity_id`
        WHERE  `sales_flat_order`.`status` !=  "Complete" AND `sales_flat_quote_address`.`address_type` = "shipping" AND `sales_flat_order_item`.`row_total` != "0"');

// output the information
while ($queryRows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlQuery)) fputcsv($outputFile, $queryRows);
```

Comment: I would look into MySQL's `GROUP BY` clause, and the MySQL string concatenation functions. You could effectively join the multiple values together delimiting them with a comma for use in your CSV.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. To anybody that is curious, I replaced `aitoc_order_entity_custom`.`value` with GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `aitoc_order_entity_custom`.`value` ) AS `value` and put GROUP BY `sales_flat_order`.`increment_id`') at the end of the query.

Comment: Do you need concat?  Why don't you just use `SELECT table1.entity_id as entity_id, table2.entity_id as entity_idt2` or something of the sort.  The problem is just that two fields have the same name? Or maybe I am misinterpreting your issue.